# Eventlistener function is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When a button is clicked I want the event listener to be removed.

```
function clickMe(f,i){
      ipcRenderer.send('click', i)

      ipcRenderer.on(`message`, function (en, message) {
        document.getElementById(`status${i}`).innerHTML = message[1];
        //ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('message') <- I don't want all listeners to be removed
      });
}
```

As shown in the code above, removeAllListeners works, however, I do not want all listeners to be removed. I believe I can use `removeListener('message', function)` but if I try to put `removeListener('message', startMe())` I get thrown an error of undefined. How would I go abouts doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is called `removeEventListener` which takes the function you want to remove as its second parameter.
You can't remove it, because the function is anonymous. If you use named functions, it should work:

```
function onMessage = function (en, message) {
    document.getElementById(`status${i}`).innerHTML = message[1];
    ipcRenderer.removeEventListener('message', onMessage);
}

function clickMe(f,i){
      ipcRenderer.send('click', i)
      ipcRenderer.on('message', onMessage);
}
```